# To open a bak file

Tags: sql-server

I want a bak file to be open in my sql server 2008 I tried to open by restore database it throws a error "that the database was backend on server running mchine version 10.50.1600.That version is incompatible with this server  which is running version 10.00.2531".Pls tell me how to open a bak file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, waht about you install the correct version of SQL Server?

If you care to read the error:

> that the database was backend on server running mchine version
>   10.50.1600.That version is incompatible with this server which is running version 10.00.2531

it is pretty clear, or? Update your SQL Server to the version that took the BAK file (or higher).

http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

can be useful to find out what we talk about.

Your server: 10.00.2531 = 2008 Sp1

Backup: 10.50.1600 = 2008 R2

Time to get an update on your machine. You run ANCIENT software - heck, 2008 r2 just dropped out of regular support. And you did not even bother to patch it - you are on SP1 level, while SP4 is the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a server mismatch. You are trying to restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a SQL Server 2008 server. You'll need to upgrade your server, or find an R2 server to do the restore.